# Programming languages and APIs licenses

Tags: licensing

I would like to write a music player for Windows, in C++ or C#, and maybe sell it. I would like to use mciSendString, and I was wondering if I would have to pay any royalties to Microsoft.

Question 1: Can I use ALL of C# .NET in making premium apps without paying for a license to Microsoft?

Question 2: If not, can I use mciSendString, again without paying any royalties to Microsoft?

Comment: you still might get better answers at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: or perhaps http://opensource.stackexchange.com/, which is still in beta

Comment: mciSendString is part of the Microsoft Windows API, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowed to do anything you want with all C# .NET features without having to pay anything to Microsoft.

C# and the .NET framework were created with the goal of being able to compete (and overtake) with existing openly available technologies such as Java. Although it seems impossible to find any official documentation that states this information outright, it is clear that Microsoft intends for these technologies to be used for anything and everything by independent developers to multinational corporations.

In addition to this, Microsoft does not have a program set up to account for each C# and .NET use, thus not being able to take royalties.